# copy multiple files from yesterday to specific folder powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy all files changed/created yesterday from a certain folder to another certain folder. It writes errors and also does not paste the files into the folder.

Here is the script:

```
$DestinationFolder = "D:\Dropbox\Public\Download\New folder"
  If(!(test-path $DestinationFolder))
  {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationFolder
  }
  $EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
     
  $Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Harel Gordon\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\" -File
    
  foreach ($File in $Files) 
  {
      if ($File.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") -eq $EarliestModifiedTime)
      {
          Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder
          Write-Host "Copying $File"
      }
      else 
      {
          Write-Host "Not copying $File"
      }
  }

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

These are the errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgTwU.png)

It worked for a while then stopped. do not know why

Comment: Change `Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder` to `$File |Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationFolder`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: +1 and "Bravo!" for knowing and sharing the best option for dealing with the `-Path` vs. `-LiteralPath` issue. For the sake of future visitorts to this forum, I thinkk you should post you solution as an `Answer` with an explantion of the issue.

Comment: @HarelGordon: For the sake of future visitors to this forum, it would be great if you edited your question and replaced the link to the image of your error and replaced it with excerpts from the output copied as text from the console and pasted into a formatted codeblock in your question. Just a couple of sample limes of "good" output, then the full text of the error message, and a few more good lines to show that processing continues.